# Adapt PHP Web Sites for Mobile Devices: Redirect to mobile subdomain "m"

Tags: php, html, redirect, mobile

I want to redirect html desktop pages to html mobile pages from the "m" subdomain. I believe I must change something in pages, so I find some settings on other web platforms. The problem is that, does not working.

In desktop pages add this code (change the link):

```html
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.yoursite.com/test.html" />

<link rel="amphtml" href="https://m.yoursite.com/test.html?amp" />
```

In mobile pages add this (change the link):

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>

<link rel="canonical" href="https://m.yoursite.com/test.html"/>

<link rel="amphtml" href="https://m.yoursite.com/test.html?amp"/>

<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.yoursite.com/test.html"/>

<meta name="cXenseParse:pageclass" content="article"/>

<meta name="cXenseParse:url" content="https://m.yoursite.com/test.html"/>

<meta name="robots" content="follow,index,noodp"/>

<meta name="robots" content="max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1"/>

<meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-cross-origin"/>

<meta property="og:url" content="https://m.yoursite.com/test.html" />
```

Do I need to change something in php? what do I have to do to work?

Answer (score 1):

Probably use [Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect), identify the device of the visitor (desktop, tablet, smartphone) and just redirect to desktop variant if necessary. Yes, this is the PHP side.

Comment: thanks, @Curanai, but it does't say where exactly I need to copy all those files. Where should I copy those ?

Comment: I don't know your project or folder structure inside of it. Mobile-Detect is an own class and there are many, many examples how to use it. But keep in mind: normally a user likes to change the view on own decision. This auto-redirect is probably unwanted by your visitors.